# Highstock with datetime and multiple columns

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I've been using HighCharts a lot in the past, but I don't remember how to render this kind of chart, with HighStocks:

I have a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    timestamp: 'Sun Aug 16 2015 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)',
    run: 2,
    rest: 3
  },
  {
    timestamp: 'Sun Aug 16 2015 10:01:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)',
    run: 4,
    rest: 1
  },
  {
   timestamp: 'Sun Aug 16 2015 10:02:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)',
   run: 2,
   rest: 1
  },
]
```

I would like to have a chart  with two columns (run and rest) per timestamp. With HighStocks, so I can define my own scale with the mouse.

How can I write this in the chart configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Highstocks, you need to pass your date in milliseconds. So you can use (supposing we are looping through your JSON array):

```
var d = new Date(json[i].timestamp);
```

Then your series will have the format:

```
[d.getTime(), json[i].rest]
```

You can see a [working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecryt9yz/), which takes your json array as data.

Comment: Thanks Kabulan0lak ;)